# Wrap Text Possible?

Tags: feature-request, support, code-formatting

Here is some code:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PATH:/home/aneesh/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/home/aneesh/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools

declare -a arr=("com.android.inputmethod.pinyin/.PinyinIME" "jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn/.OpenWnnJAJP" "com.example.android.softkeyboard/.SoftKeyboard" "com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME")

emulator @AndroidCool &
sleep 200
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
adb shell ime disable "$i"
done
```

What I want to know is how can one type the same code so that the text is automatically wrapped? In my opinion, horizontal scrolling as above isn't visually pleasing! If this is not yet an available feature, I request that it be added!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no way to automatically wrap text in code blocks right now, and I don't think we have any plans to introduce that.

Comment: Trying to read code blocks that *do* wrap is often a lot harder in my opinion (the indentation won't be right, and it's hard to automatically choose a good spot to go onto the next line).  You simply need to re-format the code to ensure that it doesn't have really long lines of text.